# How to find a substitution that transforms an equation into a particular equation. (Roots of polynomials).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Find the value of $c$ so that the substitution $x=u+c$ transforms the equation $x^3-12x^2+45x-54=0$ into the equation $u^3-3u^2=0$

My first idea is to find the roots of $u^3-3u^2=0$ And getting $u=0$ and $u=3$, however I am not sure how to continue.

If someone could explain how to tackle this sort of problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Think of how the free coefficient (the constant term) will look like after substitution and expansion: $c^3-12c^2+45c-54$. This has to be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(u+c)=(u+c)^3-12(u+c)^2+45(u+c)-54$$
In the final equation the coefficient of $u$ is $0$.
That means want to eliminate coefficient of $u$ in $f(u+c)$,
so collect the coefficients of $u$ and set it to $0$:
$$\begin{align}&3c^2-12(2c) + 45=0\\&c^2-8c+15=0\\&c=3,5\end{align}$$

Plug each of these in $f(u+c)$ and see if the constant term also gets eliminated.

Comment: $f(u+5)=u^3+3u^2-4$.

Comment: then we eliminate $c=5$ and hope $c=3$ works :)

Comment: Yes, thank you, my mistake.

Comment: It's all good. No worries:)

Comment: $\left(u+c\right)^3-12\left(u+c\right)+45\left(u+c\right)-54:\quad u^3+3cu^2+3c^2u+33u+c^3+33c-54$ Could you please share how did you reduce this? I know when you equate this to $u^3-3u^2$ you get a degree 3 polynomial in $c$, which can be solved, but it takes a complex expression not a slim one as the one you have posted. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I am also a little confused on the elimination of the coefficient of u.

Comment: @NoChance I just collected the coefficients of $u$ and set them to $0$. Also an exponent is missing in your expression:
$$\left(u+c\right)^3-12\left(u+c\right)^{\color{red}{2}}+45\left(u+c\right)-54$$

Comment: @Jamminermit If it is still unclear let me know. I'll try adding some explanation

Comment: Ok, I’m pretty confident about this now, I don’t know if I would have thought of that on my own though!

Comment: Glad to hear:) @Jamminermit Of course these things have to be taught by others who know them well. Hard to figure everything out on your own.

Comment: Yes, got it thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another more systematic way without factorization uses Taylor polynomials.

Set $f(x) = x^3-12x^2+45x-54$. Then according Taylor you have around any $a \in \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{3}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$
$$\stackrel{a=-c}{\Longrightarrow}f(x) = \frac{f^{(2)}(-c)}{2!}(x+c)^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(-c)}{3!}(x+c)^3$$

Since the coefficient in front of $u^2 = (x+c)^2$ is $-3$, the following equation must hold true 
$$\frac{f^{(2)}(-c)}{2!} \stackrel{!}{=} -3 \Leftrightarrow \frac{6(-c)-24}{2!}=-3 \Leftrightarrow \boxed{c=-3}$$

Comment: Excellent use of Taylor's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively fast approach that avoids factoring a cubic.

Notice that $u^3 - 3 u^2 = u^2 (u - 3)$ has a double root at $u = 0$, so if $x = u + c$, the given polynomial, $$p(x) := x^3 − 12 x^2 + 45 x − 54$$ has a double root at $x = (0) + c = c$.

Since $c$ is a double root, it is also a root of $$p'(x) = 3 (x^2 - 8 x + 15) = 3 (x - 3) (x - 5) ,$$ so $c = 3$ or $c = 5$. But $5 \not\mid 54$, so the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) implies that $p(5) \neq 0$, leaving
$$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{c = 3}} .$$

Comment: The idea with the double root and using the 1st derivative is also nice. So, (+1) for that.  :-)

Comment: Cheers!$\!\!\!$

Answer (score 1):

You want a factorization of the form $u^2(u-3)$. This means, the given polynomial should also factor into $(x-c)^2(x-c-3)$.

So, the first thing to do, whether you can factor the given polynomial.

Based on the [rational root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) you find quickly that your polynomial factors into

$$(x-3)^2(x-6) \Rightarrow u = x-3 \Leftrightarrow x= u+3$$

Comment: The Rational Root Test gives, I think, 16 possibilities, $1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 27, 54$ and their negatives, and it is laborious to try them all, but we can sidestep most of this work: Since the signs of the given polynomial strictly alternate, all of its roots are positive. Since the difference of the roots is $3$, consulting our list of candidates, the two roots must either be $3$ and $6$ or $6$ and $9$. In both cases $6$ is a root and so $x - 6$ is a factor, reducing the problem to factoring a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: @TravisWillse : Looking at the coefficients of the polynomial, you would quickly find that $3$ is a root. Then, for example, a polynomial division would give you a quadratic equation easy to factor. You would surely not start with $54$ to check the roots. :-)

Comment: Yes, surely not, but how would you know to start with $3$ in particular? (Either way, +1 for a clean, conceptual answer.)